# eclipse remote java debug via ant

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, remote-debugging

I use ant to make jar file, upload it on remote server, and start remote debug session on this server

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5432
```

But after that i need to choose in eclipse through remote debug launch configurations by self, my question is it possible to run exact eclipse remote debug launch configuration using some ant task?

Answer (score 0):

You cant from the same ant script (its running remote, is it?)

If you mean to have two ant scripts (one local, one remote), theres no way to do this using the default Eclipse mechanisms and API.

What you could do is to create OSGi command line component and install it as a plugin into your Eclipse IDE. Its not hard but you have to be familiar with running tasks from within the Eclipse using Java. Check out my tutorial here:

http://knol.google.com/k/creating-osgi-command-line-applications-with-equinox